# High battery consumption related to MobileSignalController logcat messages (voiceNetType 13 to 0)

Tags: android, logcat

### First, to give some context to the problem:

I'm located in Graz, Austria and I've got my Nokia 5 phone now for about two years and in the last 5-6 months my battery consumption suddenly increased without any real change of behaviour from my side. Then suddenly, on vacation in Croatia, I noticed that my battery suddenly lasted 1.5 to 2.5 days instead of the 0.5 days it lasted when I was home. Back home, my fully charged phone again only lasted about 0.5 days... At first I thought this might have been due to reduced phone usage during my vacation, but during my stay in London for droidcon one month ago, I noticed the same behaviour: Different country, lower battery consumption; back in Austria, higher battery consumption.

### MobileSignalController spamming logcat

Trying to get some information about my problem using logcat, I immediately noticed that the `MobileSignalController` component was spamming messages about a change in state with the `voiceNetType` changing from `13` to `0`. So my suspicion is that the high battery usage might be caused by some strange behaviour from my service provider (called ***bob***).

Another possible cause of the problem a colleague of mine came up with is that some app might behave differently when the phone's on roaming (just sounded reasonable to me, don't know if an app can influence `MobileSignalController`s behaviour).

### What I want to know

Since I'm not very experienced with that part of the Android OS, I'd like to know if anybody has experience with that part of the OS and what a state change like this does mean in general and what the reasons behind such a state change are.

Further, I'm also interested if there are some possibilities from a settings/software side for me as a programmer to battle this specific problem.

### Logcat output, filtered for 'mobile', for the sake of completeness

```
2019-11-25 10:44:55.483 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateTelephony: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -160 -1 27 -91 -15 0 2147483647 0 2147483647 99 -2147483529 2147483647 gsm|lte use_rsrp_and_rssnr_for_lte_level rscp [-140, -120, -113, -105] [-120, -103, -97, -89] 99 99
2019-11-25 10:44:55.483 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateVoiceNetworkType voiceNetType: 13 mCurrentState.connected: true
2019-11-25 10:44:55.489 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isShowSXLTEStyle: false isRoaming: false
2019-11-25 10:44:55.490 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:44:53,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=0strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
        to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:44:53,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=13strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
2019-11-25 10:44:55.490 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isShowSXLTEStyle: false isRoaming: false
2019-11-25 10:44:55.490 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): notifyListeners showDataIcon: true mDataType: 2131232290 mShowNoData: true mComboNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mRoamingNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mDataNetType: 13 mCurrentState.userSetup: true dataDisabled: false mCurrentState.dataConnected: true mCurrentState.imsRadioTechnology: 0 mAllowShowVoLTE[0]: false mAllowShowVoLTE[1]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[0]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[1]: false mSignalStyleCT: false SubscriptionId: 1 mShowVoLTEOption: 0 mShowVoWiFiOption: 0 mSubInfoSize: 1 mSimSlotId: 0
2019-11-25 10:44:55.493 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isMobileIms return false
2019-11-25 10:44:55.495 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isImsRegisteredInWifi return false
2019-11-25 10:44:55.495 3072-3072/? I/StatusBarSignalPolicy: setMobileDataIndicators mMobileVisible: true mMobileVisibleSim1: true mMobileVisibleSim2: true
2019-11-25 10:44:55.495 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232308 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:44:55.495 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232308 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:45:00.572 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:44:55,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=0strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
        to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=true,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:44:55,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=13strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
2019-11-25 10:45:00.572 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isShowSXLTEStyle: false isRoaming: false
2019-11-25 10:45:00.572 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): notifyListeners showDataIcon: true mDataType: 2131232290 mShowNoData: true mComboNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mRoamingNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mDataNetType: 13 mCurrentState.userSetup: true dataDisabled: false mCurrentState.dataConnected: true mCurrentState.imsRadioTechnology: 0 mAllowShowVoLTE[0]: false mAllowShowVoLTE[1]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[0]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[1]: false mSignalStyleCT: false SubscriptionId: 1 mShowVoLTEOption: 0 mShowVoWiFiOption: 0 mSubInfoSize: 1 mSimSlotId: 0
2019-11-25 10:45:00.578 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isMobileIms return false
2019-11-25 10:45:00.579 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isImsRegisteredInWifi return false
2019-11-25 10:45:00.579 3072-3072/? I/StatusBarSignalPolicy: setMobileDataIndicators mMobileVisible: true mMobileVisibleSim1: true mMobileVisibleSim2: true
2019-11-25 10:45:00.593 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232304 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:45:00.593 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232304 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:45:01.578 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=true,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:45:00,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=0strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
        to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:45:00,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=13strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
2019-11-25 10:45:01.578 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isShowSXLTEStyle: false isRoaming: false
2019-11-25 10:45:01.578 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): notifyListeners showDataIcon: true mDataType: 2131232290 mShowNoData: true mComboNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mRoamingNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mDataNetType: 13 mCurrentState.userSetup: true dataDisabled: false mCurrentState.dataConnected: true mCurrentState.imsRadioTechnology: 0 mAllowShowVoLTE[0]: false mAllowShowVoLTE[1]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[0]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[1]: false mSignalStyleCT: false SubscriptionId: 1 mShowVoLTEOption: 0 mShowVoWiFiOption: 0 mSubInfoSize: 1 mSimSlotId: 0
2019-11-25 10:45:01.598 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isMobileIms return false
2019-11-25 10:45:01.599 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isImsRegisteredInWifi return false
2019-11-25 10:45:01.600 3072-3072/? I/StatusBarSignalPolicy: setMobileDataIndicators mMobileVisible: true mMobileVisibleSim1: true mMobileVisibleSim2: true
2019-11-25 10:45:01.615 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232308 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:45:01.615 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232308 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:45:02.203 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateTelephony: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -160 -1 27 -91 -13 9 2147483647 0 2147483647 99 -2147483529 2147483647 gsm|lte use_rsrp_and_rssnr_for_lte_level rscp [-140, -120, -113, -105] [-120, -103, -97, -89] 99 99
2019-11-25 10:45:02.203 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateVoiceNetworkType voiceNetType: 13 mCurrentState.connected: true
2019-11-25 10:45:02.205 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isShowSXLTEStyle: false isRoaming: false
2019-11-25 10:45:02.206 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:45:01,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=0strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
        to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:45:01,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=13strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
2019-11-25 10:45:02.206 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isShowSXLTEStyle: false isRoaming: false
2019-11-25 10:45:02.207 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): notifyListeners showDataIcon: true mDataType: 2131232290 mShowNoData: true mComboNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mRoamingNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mDataNetType: 13 mCurrentState.userSetup: true dataDisabled: false mCurrentState.dataConnected: true mCurrentState.imsRadioTechnology: 0 mAllowShowVoLTE[0]: false mAllowShowVoLTE[1]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[0]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[1]: false mSignalStyleCT: false SubscriptionId: 1 mShowVoLTEOption: 0 mShowVoWiFiOption: 0 mSubInfoSize: 1 mSimSlotId: 0
2019-11-25 10:45:02.210 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isMobileIms return false
2019-11-25 10:45:02.212 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isImsRegisteredInWifi return false
2019-11-25 10:45:02.212 3072-3072/? I/StatusBarSignalPolicy: setMobileDataIndicators mMobileVisible: true mMobileVisibleSim1: true mMobileVisibleSim2: true
2019-11-25 10:45:02.213 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232308 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:45:02.213 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232308 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:45:04.443 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateTelephony: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -160 -1 27 -92 -12 24 2147483647 0 2147483647 99 -2147483529 2147483647 gsm|lte use_rsrp_and_rssnr_for_lte_level rscp [-140, -120, -113, -105] [-120, -103, -97, -89] 99 99
2019-11-25 10:45:04.443 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateVoiceNetworkType voiceNetType: 13 mCurrentState.connected: true
2019-11-25 10:45:04.445 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isShowSXLTEStyle: false isRoaming: false
2019-11-25 10:45:04.447 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:45:02,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=0strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
        to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:45:02,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=13strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
2019-11-25 10:45:04.447 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isShowSXLTEStyle: false isRoaming: false
2019-11-25 10:45:04.447 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): notifyListeners showDataIcon: true mDataType: 2131232290 mShowNoData: true mComboNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mRoamingNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mDataNetType: 13 mCurrentState.userSetup: true dataDisabled: false mCurrentState.dataConnected: true mCurrentState.imsRadioTechnology: 0 mAllowShowVoLTE[0]: false mAllowShowVoLTE[1]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[0]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[1]: false mSignalStyleCT: false SubscriptionId: 1 mShowVoLTEOption: 0 mShowVoWiFiOption: 0 mSubInfoSize: 1 mSimSlotId: 0
2019-11-25 10:45:04.451 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isMobileIms return false
2019-11-25 10:45:04.452 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isImsRegisteredInWifi return false
2019-11-25 10:45:04.455 3072-3072/? I/StatusBarSignalPolicy: setMobileDataIndicators mMobileVisible: true mMobileVisibleSim1: true mMobileVisibleSim2: true
2019-11-25 10:45:04.455 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232308 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:45:04.455 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232308 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:45:08.859 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateTelephony: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -160 -1 28 -91 -13 44 2147483647 0 2147483647 99 -2147483529 2147483647 gsm|lte use_rsrp_and_rssnr_for_lte_level rscp [-140, -120, -113, -105] [-120, -103, -97, -89] 99 99
2019-11-25 10:45:08.859 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateVoiceNetworkType voiceNetType: 13 mCurrentState.connected: true
2019-11-25 10:45:08.861 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isShowSXLTEStyle: false isRoaming: false
2019-11-25 10:45:08.862 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:45:04,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=0strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
        to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:45:04,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=13strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
2019-11-25 10:45:08.862 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isShowSXLTEStyle: false isRoaming: false
2019-11-25 10:45:08.862 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): notifyListeners showDataIcon: true mDataType: 2131232290 mShowNoData: true mComboNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mRoamingNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mDataNetType: 13 mCurrentState.userSetup: true dataDisabled: false mCurrentState.dataConnected: true mCurrentState.imsRadioTechnology: 0 mAllowShowVoLTE[0]: false mAllowShowVoLTE[1]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[0]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[1]: false mSignalStyleCT: false SubscriptionId: 1 mShowVoLTEOption: 0 mShowVoWiFiOption: 0 mSubInfoSize: 1 mSimSlotId: 0
2019-11-25 10:45:08.868 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isMobileIms return false
2019-11-25 10:45:08.870 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isImsRegisteredInWifi return false
2019-11-25 10:45:08.870 3072-3072/? I/StatusBarSignalPolicy: setMobileDataIndicators mMobileVisible: true mMobileVisibleSim1: true mMobileVisibleSim2: true
2019-11-25 10:45:08.870 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232308 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:45:08.870 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232308 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
2019-11-25 10:45:10.214 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): Change in state from: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:45:08,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=0strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
        to: connected=true,enabled=true,level=4,inetCondition=1,iconGroup=IconGroup(4G),activityIn=false,activityOut=false,rssi=0,lastModified=11-25 10:45:08,dataSim=true,networkName=bob,networkNameData=bob,dataConnected=true,roaming=false,isDefault=true,isEmergency=false,airplaneMode=false,carrierNetworkChangeMode=false,userSetup=true,imsRadioTechnology=0,comboTypeIcon=2131232334,roamingIcon=0,voiceNetType=13strengthIconCT=0,carrierConfigUpdated=1,voiceLevel=0,dataActivity=0
2019-11-25 10:45:10.215 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isShowSXLTEStyle: false isRoaming: false
2019-11-25 10:45:10.215 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): notifyListeners showDataIcon: true mDataType: 2131232290 mShowNoData: true mComboNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mRoamingNetworkTypeIconId: 0 mDataNetType: 13 mCurrentState.userSetup: true dataDisabled: false mCurrentState.dataConnected: true mCurrentState.imsRadioTechnology: 0 mAllowShowVoLTE[0]: false mAllowShowVoLTE[1]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[0]: false mAllowShowVoWiFi[1]: false mSignalStyleCT: false SubscriptionId: 1 mShowVoLTEOption: 0 mShowVoWiFiOption: 0 mSubInfoSize: 1 mSimSlotId: 0
2019-11-25 10:45:10.225 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isMobileIms return false
2019-11-25 10:45:10.226 3072-3265/? I/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): isImsRegisteredInWifi return false
2019-11-25 10:45:10.226 3072-3072/? I/StatusBarSignalPolicy: setMobileDataIndicators mMobileVisible: true mMobileVisibleSim1: true mMobileVisibleSim2: true
2019-11-25 10:45:10.226 3072-3072/? D/StatusBarVolteView: states = [MobileIconState(subId=1, strengthId=2131232326, roaming=false, typeId=2131232290, volteId=0, visible=true mDataArrowId=2131232308 mComboNetworkTypeId=0mRoamingNetworkTypeId=0 mVoLTEOption=0 mVoWiFiOption=0 mSubscriptionSize=1 mImsOverWifi=false mMobileIms=false),5GState(fiveGIconVisible=false, fiveGStrengthId=66560, dataOnFiveG=false, is4GStateVisible=true)] visible = true
...
```

this goes on for some thousand lines...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK , The Battery drain doesn't depend on home or roaming network. But it depends on when you are travelling , Lets assume if you are travelling it would drain the battery more as its switching towers and trying to find the signal and on exploring your logs i can see that its trying to connect to the signals , Lets assume the signal might have been weaker in places and the device would have a hard time finding signals and due to which its draining the battery , More over on exploring your logs found out that updateTelephony has been called several times which is like a lister method which is used to update the state when there is a change in the signal parameters like (mServiceState, mSignalStrength, mDataNetType,mDataState, and mSimState), Here below is the method from the framework which could explain the same.

```
2019-11-25 10:44:55.483 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateTelephony: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -160 -1 27 -91 -15 0 2147483647 0 2147483647 99 -2147483529 2147483647 gsm|lte use_rsrp_and_rssnr_for_lte_level rscp [-140, -120, -113, -105] [-120, -103, -97, -89] 99 99
2019-11-25 10:45:02.203 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateTelephony: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -160 -1 27 -91 -13 9 2147483647 0 2147483647 99 -2147483529 2147483647 gsm|lte use_rsrp_and_rssnr_for_lte_level rscp [-140, -120, -113, -105] [-120, -103, -97, -89] 99 99
2019-11-25 10:45:04.443 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateTelephony: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -160 -1 27 -92 -12 24 2147483647 0 2147483647 99 -2147483529 2147483647 gsm|lte use_rsrp_and_rssnr_for_lte_level rscp [-140, -120, -113, -105] [-120, -103, -97, -89] 99 99
2019-11-25 10:45:08.859 3072-3265/? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): updateTelephony: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -160 -1 28 -91 -13 44 2147483647 0 2147483647 99 -2147483529 2147483647 gsm|lte use_rsrp_and_rssnr_for_lte_level rscp [-140, -120, -113, -105] [-120, -103, -97, -89] 99 99
```

Source code of the updateTelephony method from the Framework:

```
private final void updateTelephony() {
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.d(mTag, "updateTelephonySignalStrength: hasService=" + hasService()
                + " ss=" + mSignalStrength);
    }
    mCurrentState.connected = hasService() && mSignalStrength != null;
    if (mCurrentState.connected) {
        if (!mSignalStrength.isGsm() && mConfig.alwaysShowCdmaRssi) {
            mCurrentState.level = mSignalStrength.getCdmaLevel();
        } else {
            mCurrentState.level = mSignalStrength.getLevel();
        }
    }
    if (mNetworkToIconLookup.indexOfKey(mDataNetType) >= 0) {
        mCurrentState.iconGroup = mNetworkToIconLookup.get(mDataNetType);
    } else {
        mCurrentState.iconGroup = mDefaultIcons;
    }
    mCurrentState.dataConnected = mCurrentState.connected
            && mDataState == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED;
    if (isCarrierNetworkChangeActive()) {
        mCurrentState.iconGroup = TelephonyIcons.CARRIER_NETWORK_CHANGE;
    } else if (isRoaming()) {
        mCurrentState.iconGroup = TelephonyIcons.ROAMING;
    }
    if (isEmergencyOnly() != mCurrentState.isEmergency) {
        mCurrentState.isEmergency = isEmergencyOnly();
        mNetworkController.recalculateEmergency();
    }
    // Fill in the network name if we think we have it.
    if (mCurrentState.networkName == mNetworkNameDefault && mServiceState != null
            && mServiceState.getOperatorAlphaShort() != null) {
        mCurrentState.networkName = mServiceState.getOperatorAlphaShort();
    }
    notifyListenersIfNecessary();
}
```

Code Source :

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/33f8ae7/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/MobileSignalController.java

Comment: Thank you for the work you put into your answer, it was kind of informative and caused me to further try out some stuff. Apparently, when setting the preferred network type in the mobile network settings to 3G instead of 4G, the `MobileSignalController` doesn't spam Logcat anymore... Will need to investigate if my battery life increases again, but for now, its a promising lead. Will report back as soon as I have some further clues :)